# Adobe AIR 3.8 Flash Builder 4.6 for iOS - Secondary SWF with Actionscript works on fast packaging but fails on Releast Build

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air

I have a simple Flex Mobile project that just allows user to swap between 2 different .swf games.  I load the .swf with the following code:

```
private function loadFile(f:String):void{   
            var _urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(f);
            var _loader:Loader = new Loader();
            var _lc:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain, null);
            _loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSWFLoaded);
            _loader.load(_urlRequest, _lc);
            txt.text="loading";
            // add loader to container
            grp.addChild(_loader);
        }
        private function onSWFLoaded(e:Event):void {
            // status text to show it loaded
            txt.text="loaded!";
        }
```

Then on user button click I just do:

```
 loadFile("file1.swf");
```

file1.swf is packaged into the build.  I run this on debug under fast packaging on my iPod Touch and everything works like a charm, but when I do an export release build, my status text still says "loaded", but the swf loads very strangely - as if there's some code that is failing to run properly.

Since it works on fast packaging with no issue, what would be the difference between release build and fast build that can cause code in child swfs to fail?

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Loading SWFs at runtime was not allowed on iOS for the longest time because it was against the iOS Developer agreement.  I think it had something to do w/ interpreting items at runtime vs compile time.  It is only recently that Flash started doing this; but I have no idea what the behind the scenes implementation is. But, whatever they do it is most certainly different and that is probably why you're having errors.

Comment: Afaik you can load swfs, but they're content only; you can't have code in them

Comment: More info here: http://blogs.adobe.com/airodynamics/2012/11/09/packaging-and-loading-multiple-swfs-in-air-apps-on-ios/

Comment: I have read that article - but I do not get the error of uncompiled actionscript.  The app just loads very strangely, as if it's stuck in a loop.

Comment: Try load test SWF with simple graphics and add code in frame to move/change something a little , You will see if it loads and code is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issues based on comments from here:
http://forums.adobe.com/message/5398137

Using var file:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("file1.swf"); and adding the Flex Compiler option "swf-version=19" fixed the issue for me.  Not sure which one of the two changes fixed it but it all works now.